# glIsBuffer unexpected result

Tags: opengl, c++

```
static void BindBuffer(BufferTarget target, GLuint buffer)
{
    if(!glIsBuffer(buffer))
        throw runtime_error("This is not a buffer. WTF?");

    glBindBuffer((GLenum)target,buffer);
    check_gl_error();
}
```

In my app, this always throws the exception. However, if I remove the `glIsBuffer()` check, everything works fine. Suggestions?

**Update**

Okay, turns out that glIsBuffer() returns false if the buffer is not bound. Is this expected behavior? If so, how do I check if a buffer handle is valid before attempting to bind it? calling glBindBuffer() then checking for an error seems like a stupid way to accomplish this.

**THE NEW QUESTION**

I'd start a new thread, but seems silly since it's directly related to the original post:

Is there a way to determine if a handle refers to a GL object (buffer, program, shader, etc) without trying to bind it first? Is it really recommended practice to bind it, then check for an error?

Comment: Remove the `glIsBuffer()` check is probably a good suggestion.

Comment: @Byte56 yeah, but the idea is to find out if `buffer` is a valid handle before trying to bind it. Seems I'm going about this the wrong way. I'd love a reference to the *right* way to do it. Oh, how I miss OpenTK...

Comment: See http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glIsBuffer.xml ... it seems to indicate that it must be bound first.

Comment: Try, then check for error is a common practice and I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: @Byte56 just feels weird coming from an an environment where you get an exception if something goes haywire. I can work with it - I'm wrapping everything anyway. Probably a side effect of coming from C# back to C++. (Hint to others: because you used to know C, and are an expert in C#, does NOT mean you know C++.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand this we must look at how a buffer object is initially specified.

1. First of all we call glGenBuffers to create a name for the object.
2. Then we call glBindBuffer to bind the object to the GL context, and this also associates it with a buffer type via the target parameter.
3. Finally we make our initial glBufferData (or optionally glBufferStorage with GL4.4) call to specify it's storage.

Looking over [the glIsBuffer documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glIsBuffer.xml), particularly this part:

> A name returned by glGenBuffers, but not yet associated with a buffer object by calling glBindBuffer, is not the name of a buffer object.

It seems clear that both 1 and 2 must be done before glIsBuffer will return GL_TRUE.  However, once that condition has been satisfied, glIsBuffer for the same name will **always** return GL_TRUE, even if that buffer name is not currently bound, and until glDeleteBuffers is called for the name (or the context is destroyed and recreated).

This makes sense because all that glGenBuffers does is give you an unused buffer object name.  The name hasn't been associated with a buffer object yet; you're free to do anything you want with it, including not even use the name.  The association of a name with a buffer object happens during the first glBindBuffer call that uses the name: we're using that name now, so it's no longer free, so glIsBuffer can return GL_TRUE for that name.

This behaviour is also documented for [glGenBuffers](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glGenBuffers.xml):

> No buffer objects are associated with the returned buffer object names until they are first bound by calling glBindBuffer.

Note that the documentation is consistent for both - it's the **first** binding that creates the association, so it's only the **first** binding that is required for glIsBuffer to return GL_TRUE.

In other words, and unless you've got a driver bug, the following tests should run as expected:

```
GLuint testBuffers[2] = {0, 0};
GLboolean isBuffer[2] = {GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE};

glGenBuffers (2, testBuffers);  // just generate names; they're not buffers yet

isBuffer[0] = glIsBuffer (testBuffers[0]);  // returns GL_FALSE
isBuffer[1] = glIsBuffer (testBuffers[1]);  // returns GL_FALSE

glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, testBuffers[0]); // this is a buffer now
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, testBuffers[1]); // this is a buffer now
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);  // no binding

isBuffer[0] = glIsBuffer (testBuffers[0]);  // returns GL_TRUE
isBuffer[1] = glIsBuffer (testBuffers[1]);  // returns GL_TRUE
```

It seems evident that you're calling your `BindBuffer` function as part of your buffer object creation, so it's happening in-between steps 1 and 2 above; if that's the case then yes, it's expected that your initial glIsBuffer call is going to return GL_FALSE.

Personally I'd advise that you refactor your buffer object creation.  The 3 steps (glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData) can be combined into a single function.  Save your own `BindBuffer` call for subsequent (i.e. post-creation) use instead, as use of it for creation (if I'm right) is the root cause of your problem.